# Unable to string value of object field using property

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, foreach

I'm currently working on some code. I will cut short on the details but this is what I experience:

This is the class `BookingObject`:

```
public class BookingObject
{
    public BookingObject(int id, DateTime starttime)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.starttime = starttime;
    }
   public int id {get; set;}
   public datetime {get; set;}
}
```

This is the `webform.aspx`:

```
  List<BookingObject> bo = new List<BookingObject>();

  foreach (BookingObject book in bo)
  {
      int avcde = book.starttime.Hour;
      //starttime is DateTime
      TextBox1.Text = avcde.toString();
  }
```

When I display the variable `avcde` in some textbox, it shows `null`. 
I tried to debug and flag the assignment line, the debugger shows the variable `avcde` is `0`, but the `book.starttime.Hour` shows some integer value. The assignment from the `book.starttime.Hour` to the variable `avcde` is unsuccessful.

May I know what's wrong with that?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? for example the class definition of BookingObject and the assignment to the textbox would be useful ...

Comment: int cannot be assigned null.  It defaults to 0.  The issue is somewhere else.  Where's the control assignment code?

Comment: There's no problem in this code as far as I see. Maybe you're doing something else wrong? What does the BookingObject constructor do? Where are you adding items to the list? Maybe you're using Multithreading or some other fancy stuff?

Answer (score 2):

As your question is basic I will give a basic answer... a variable created within a foreach loop will be destroyed after the foreach loop. Without the rest of your code it'll be hard to diagnose the issue more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems very strange that a non nullable int can return null, is impossible i think, because the default value would be zero ...

However have you tried to assign directly the value in the textBox after the for each loop? try something like this :

```
List<BookingObject> bo = new List<BookingObject>();
  DateTime dt;
  foreach (BookingObject book in bo)
  {
      dt = book.starttime;

  }
  //starttime is DateTime
  TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Hour);
```

Try with this code and see the result ...

Are you sure that the TextBox.Text property is not assigned again after this piece of code ?

Comment: it doesn't work, there's something wrong when assigning book.starttime to the variable dt, it shows 0 for the dt.Hour.While debugging, the dt value shows something like '1/1/0001 12:00:00:000' and the starttime is '3/15/2012 8:00:00:000'

Comment: It means that the book.starttime is null in your class, and that is the problem ...

Comment: sorry, i mean 0 in dt.Hour, ive edited the previous comment :-). The id is succesfully displayed in the other textbox, it's just the date